# c# ADAL v1.x pass user credentials without browser window

Tags: c#, azure, adal, azure-sdk-.net

I have some problem with ADAL version 1.x
I need to obtain user credentials on my own way, not with ADAL browser window, but I don't know how to pass these credentials to AcquireToken method.

Unfortunately I cannot use version 2.x of ADAL, because is not supported in .net 4.0.

Comment: Are you using "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" nuget? Which specific version are you using? Are you able to share the code and how you are not able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

WHat you are trying to accomplish is not supported in ADAL v1.x.
ADAL v1.x does not support the direct use of user credentials - we introduced that feature from ADAL 2.x onward.